# What does the code in the description mean, it is roblox lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I am a beginner in Roblox Lua code and I am trying to understand things in the developer forums, but I am struggling with stuff like this. One of my questions is, what is **for i, player in pairs** near the bottom

````
 
-- Remove player's character from workspace on death
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    while true do
        local char = player.CharacterAdded:wait()
        char.Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
            char:Remove()
        end)
    end
end)
 
-- Respawn all dead players once every 10 seconds
while true do
    local players = game.Players:GetChildren()
    
    -- Check if each player is dead by checking if they have no character, if dead load that player's character
    for i, player in pairs (players) do     
        if (not game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(player.Name)) then
            player:LoadCharacter()
        end
    end
 
    -- Wait 10 seconds until next respawn check
    wait(10)
end```
````

Comment: It's usually best to only attach relevant code in the question (In this case only the `for i, player...` part. The question title should also be the actual question. If stackoverflow complains that a question with that title already exists, chances are you'll find your answer there :D

Answer (score 0):

`pairs(tab)` returns a key and a value pair for every entry in a table.

```
for key, value in pairs( tab ) do
    --  do stuff here
end
```

It will do something to each of those entries in the table.

---

People often shorten it down to

```
for k, v in pairs( tab ) do
    --  do stuff here
end
```

It doesn't really matter what you call them, as long as you know what they are.  Sometimes people put in a _ blank space to indicate they aren't using that particular key or value.  The point is, 'players' is a table, so they are looping over it's contents.

---

```
for i, player in pairs( players ) do
    --  do stuff here
end
```

This is the exact same thing as written above, except they changed those "key, value" variable names
so that 'i' is now the key, and 'player' is the value.

Comment: For sequences, it's usually better to use `ipairs` though

Answer (score -1):

That would be what's known as a "for loop" in coding.

Read more about Roblox Lua loops here:

[Roblox lua loops](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Loops)

As you can see in the comment, the purpose of that bit is to determine if the player is dead. If they are dead, load the character.

For instance in python, "players" would be some iterable object like a list or dictionary. "i", "player" would stand for the objects contained in that list.

For instance:

```
def loop():
    example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    for number in example_list:
    print(number)

loop()
```

Would return:

```
1
2
3
4
```

In your case, the loop is iterating through a list of players, and checking each one to see if they are dead. If dead, respawn the player.

Comment: what do "while true do" mean?

Comment: While True: is a way to kick off a while loop. It basically means "while true == true, (which is always true), do something".. so the loop will always execute. Another way to write this is "while 1 == 1: do something". Just a heads up, you're going to get a lot of downvotes around here and eventually be banned from asking questions if you continue to ask questions that are obvious you put 0 effort into trying to research yourself. If my answer answered your question, please accept it as the answer (click the checkmark next to my answer).

Comment: Boog, why did you answer a lua question with a python example? For a beginner trying to learn lua syntax, throwing another language into the mix seems unhelpful.

Comment: @Kylaaa, well because it seems like the poster doesn't understand the fundamentals of writing any type of code... I was just explaining what the loops do, and imo python is the most easily readable/translatable language to english. OP isn't asking a specific Lua related question... they're asking "what is a "for loop".